# CreateInstance from another appdomain works on console application but throws MissingMethodException when unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, marshalling, appdomain

This is the best I can do to get the Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (You can just copy/paste to test) :

Consider these two classes:

```
public class WorkerParam : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private readonly string s;

    public WorkerParam(string s)
    {
        this.s = s;
    }
}

public class Worker : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public WorkerParam T { get; }

    public Worker(WorkerParam t)
    {
        this.T = t;
    }
}
```

Works great when run from console application (4.5.2, AnyCPU):

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Worker localWorker = new Worker(new WorkerParam("some string"));

        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");

        Worker remoteWorker = (Worker)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
            typeof(Worker).Assembly.Location,
            typeof(Worker).FullName,
            true,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new object[] { new WorkerParam("string") },
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The same content throws `MissingMethodException` when unit-testing (4.5.2, AnyCPU) :

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        Worker localWorker = new Worker(new WorkerParam("some string"));

        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");

        // below line will throw MissingMethodException
        Worker remoteWorker = (Worker)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
            typeof(Worker).Assembly.Location,
            typeof(Worker).FullName,
            true,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, null, new object[] { new WorkerParam("string") },
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);
    }
}
```

The issue is : `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` will throws  `MissingMethodException` when run from unit test (Visual studio unit) but run perfectly on a console app.

**Important** : When I remove parameter WorkerParam from constructor, it works perfectly.

Comment: It is a DLL Hell problem, you are probably running your unit test with an old copy of the assembly that contains the Worker and WorkerParam types.  An old version that did not yet have a constructor with the WorkerParam argument.

Comment: I've clean and rebuild the solution but it doesn't solve the problem. Or have I to do something else?

Comment: If you have no idea where the DLL came from then use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds.

Comment: I put the class Worker and WorkerParam in the **same file** as UnitTest1, I removed the reference to the old dll .And it's still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the location of your assemblies since you are using more than just the Worker type:

```
        AppDomainSetup domaininfo = new AppDomainSetup();
        domaininfo.ApplicationBase = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New Domain", null, domaininfo);


        Worker remoteWorker = (Worker)ad.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
            typeof(Worker).Assembly.Location,
            typeof(Worker).FullName,
            true,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            null,
            new object[] { new WorkerParam("string") },
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, null);
```